# STM32 DAC sinewave generation

Tags: stm32, adc, dac

I generated according to [this document](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00259245-audio-and-waveform-generation-using-the-dac-in-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) two same sine waves (on two pins of the microcontroller DAC). I display them on the oscilloscope and obviously overlap.
Now I would like to offset the first one by 90 degrees from the second one. I tried doing this but nothing happens, they overlap on the oscilloscope:

*outside the main*
[image]

*inside the main*
[image]

The problem is that I can't relate the stm32 DAC formula used back to the [classical sine wave formula](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=ZJUDZDK4&id=69D4141BA2FBD34AA1A6FE88FE34912087D9CA09&thid=OIP.ZJUDZDK4WVPrKMrE9JrVGwHaEK&mediaurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FBXi4_bK7zTQ%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&cdnurl=https%3A%2F%2Fth.bing.com%2Fth%2Fid%2FR.6495036432b85953eb28cac4f49ad51b%3Frik%3DCcrZhyCRNP6I%252fg%26pid%3DImgRaw%26r%3D0&exph=720&expw=1280&q=sinwave%20formula&simid=608039938111662389&FORM=IRPRST&ck=AD1133520EA7104F2315F91CA857A143&selectedIndex=1&itb=0&ajaxhist=0&ajaxserp=0) ... I don't understand where to add the phase shift.

Comment: You have added it correctly. What is the question?

Comment: What value are you using for phase2??  Are you supplying it in radians?

Comment: please post text, not a picture of text

Comment: phase2 = pi/2. The problem is that (with this code) at the oscilloscope the two sinewaves are still the same (one on the top of the other one). So before I check everything else in main.c I want to make sure I've written a correct equation.

Comment: Where are you writing the data to a port??  Show us those lines.  Note that your comments show the same field for both variables in the pdf.

Comment: What's the value of "samples"?

Comment: In general, though, the easiest way to induce a phase shift for stuff like this, in a low-ish resource embedded environment, is just to use ONE lookup table, and just offset the pointer.

Comment: In other words, if you have your indexing variable, N, and you needed a phase corresponding to 256 samples (for example) for a 2048-length array, and you're looping though N, output 1 would be indexed by sin_val[N]; N=[N+1]%2048; and the second out would be sin_val[(N+256)%2048]; N=N+1%2048;

Comment: @KaleM You can easily check the results of your equation. You can compile the code on PC or use debugger on STM32 to find out if the data is correct or not. The problem likely isn't in the code part you show, and in fact the shown part is not specific to MCUs or electronics.

Comment: @ScottSeidman apologies, I just updated the code in the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lot's of problems here show up in your edit.

The first is how you index into your array. You define the array to have 100 elements, and then you try to assign values to the 2048th element (max).  Next, you lose a lot of precision in your phase value, which is defined to be an integer, so phase2= PI/2 = 1

Start by replacing i in indices with [i%100], use an additional modulo operator to make sure the addition of phase2 doesn't overflow your array size, and make phase2 a float or double.

Comment: Thank you! Everything works now! I spent a long time trying to figure out what was wrong with the formula ... and finally made a silly mistake in the for loop.

Comment: Good Job, @KaleM -- just make sure that there are no discontinuities as you shift from the end of your array back to the beginning using the modulo functions.  The array needs to be the right size to make this work right.

Comment: I take the opportunity to ask you for some more information. What if I replace 2048 with 100 in the loop? That is, the for loop counts exactly as much as the size of the arrays, so I don't use the % operator

Comment: @KaleM -- I'm not the DMA guy, so I can't tell you why it was 2048 in the first place.  In any case, if it has nothing to do with DMA, it will work for the first array, but you'll still "fall off the end" for the second array, because of the addition of phase to the  index, and you must still use the modulo

Comment: Sorry, @Kale, that last comment of mine is just not correct -- I'll leave it in for the time being, so people can follow along.  You're not, in fact, indexing incorrectly in that loop if the top index is 100.  Should work.